Question about Synthetic Control Method in ADH JASA 2010
I'm reading the famous JASA 2010 paper (https://web.stanford.edu/~jhain/Paper/JASA2010.pdf) by ADH and encounter a question in the Appendix B. The brief summary of my question is stated below and a complete description of the setup is quoted from the paper at the end.
My Question:
Under appropriate assumptions (Invertible $\lambda^{P'}\lambda^P$ etc) in a linear factor model setup, ADH show that the outcome variable $Y_{1 t}^{N}-\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j}^{*} Y_{j t}^{N}$ can be decomposed into $Y_{1 t}^{N}-\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j}^{*} Y_{j t}^{N}=R_{1 t}+R_{2 t}+R_{3 t}$, where
$$
\begin{aligned}
& R_{1 t}=\lambda_{t}\left(\lambda^{P^{\prime}} \lambda^{P}\right)^{-1} \lambda^{P \prime} \sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j}^{*} \varepsilon_{j}^{P} \\
& R_{2 t}=-\lambda_{t}\left(\lambda^{P \prime} \lambda^{P}\right)^{-1} \lambda^{P^{\prime}} \varepsilon_{1}^{P}\\
& R_{3 t}=\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j}^{*}\left(\varepsilon_{j t}-\varepsilon_{1 t}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Then, they state:

Consider the case of $t>T_{0}$. Then, $R_{2 t}$ and $R_{3 t}$ have mean zero. Notice that,
$$
R_{1 t}=\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j}^{*} \sum_{s=1}^{T_{0}} \lambda_{t}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{T_{0}} \lambda_{n}^{\prime} \lambda_{n}\right)^{-1} \lambda_{s}^{\prime} \varepsilon_{j s}
$$

Then the Appendix proceeds with Rosenthal Inequality to show $R_{1t}$ approaches zero when $T_0$ goes to infinity. My question arises at this step: It is obvious to me that $R_{2t},R_{3t}$ have mean zero, but why it is not the case that $R_{1t}$ has mean zero? Is there some technicality I overlooked?
A Complete Quotation of the Setup:

Consider
$$
Y_{i t}^{N}=\delta_{t}+\boldsymbol{\theta}_{t} \mathbf{Z}_{i}+\lambda_{t} \boldsymbol{\mu}_{i}+\varepsilon_{i t}
$$
where $\lambda_{t}=\left(\lambda_{t 1}, \ldots, \lambda_{t F}\right)$ is a $(1 \times F)$ vector of common factors, for $t=1, \ldots, T$, and $\boldsymbol{\mu}_{i}=\left(\mu_{i 1}, \ldots, \mu_{i F}\right)^{\prime}$ is an $(F \times 1)$ vector of factor loadings, for $i=1, \ldots, J+1$. The weighted average of the outcome in the donor pool, using weights $\left\{w_{j}\right\}_{2 \leq j \leq J+1}$ is
$$
\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j} Y_{j t}^{N}=\delta_{t}+\boldsymbol{\theta}_{t}\left(\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j} \mathbf{Z}_{j}\right)+\lambda_{t}\left(\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j} \boldsymbol{\mu}_{j}\right)+\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j} \varepsilon_{j t}
$$
As a result,
$$
Y_{1 t}^{N}-\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j} Y_{j t}^{N}=\boldsymbol{\theta}_{t}\left(\mathbf{Z}_{1} -\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j} \mathbf{Z}_{j}\right) +\lambda_{t}\left(\boldsymbol{\mu}_{1}-\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j} \boldsymbol{\mu}_{j}\right)+\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j}\left(\varepsilon_{1 t}-\varepsilon_{j t}\right)
$$
We assume that the terms $\varepsilon_{i t}$ are independent across units and in time. The analysis can, however, be extended to more general settings. Notice that even with $\varepsilon_{i t}$ independent across units and in time, the unobserved residual $u_{i t}=\lambda_{t} \mu_{i}+\varepsilon_{i t}$ may be correlated across units and in time because the presence of the term $\lambda_{t} \mu_{i}$. Assume also that the terms $\varepsilon_{i t}$ are mean-independent of $\left\{\mathbf{Z}_{i}, \boldsymbol{\mu}_{i}\right\}_{i=1}^{J+1}$. Let $\mathbf{Y}_{i}^{P}$ be the $T_{0} \times 1$ vector with $t$ th element equal to $Y_{i t}$. Similarly, let $\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{i}^{P}$ be the $\left(T_{0} \times\right.$ 1) vector with th element equal to $\varepsilon_{i t}$. Finally, let $\boldsymbol{\theta}^{P}$ and $\lambda^{P}$ be the $\left(T_{0} \times r\right)$ matrix and $\left(T_{0} \times F\right)$ matrix with $t$ th rows equal to $\boldsymbol{\theta}_{t}$ and $\lambda_{t}$, respectively. We obtain,
$$
\mathbf{Y}_{1}^{P}-\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j} \mathbf{Y}_{j}^{P}=\boldsymbol{\theta}^{P}\left(\mathbf{Z}_{1}-\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j} \mathbf{Z}_{j}\right) +\lambda^{P}\left(\boldsymbol{\mu}_{1}-\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j} \boldsymbol{\mu}_{j}\right)+\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j}\left(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{1}^{P}-\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{j}^{P}\right)
$$
Let $\xi(M)$ be the smallest eigenvalue of
$$
\frac{1}{M} \sum_{t=T_{0}-M+1}^{T_{0}} \lambda_{t}^{\prime} \lambda_{t}
$$
Assume that $\xi(M)$ is bounded away from zero: $\xi(M) \geq \xi>0$, for each positive integer, $M$. Assume also that there exists a constant, $\bar{\lambda}$, such that $\left|\lambda_{t f}\right| \leq \bar{\lambda}$ for all $t=1, \ldots, T, f=1, \ldots, F$. Therefore, because $\lambda^{P /} \lambda^{P}$ is not singular:
$$
\begin{aligned}
Y_{1 t}^{N}-\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j} Y_{j t}^{N}= & \lambda_{t}\left(\lambda^{P^{\prime}} \lambda^{P}\right)^{-1} \lambda^{P^{\prime}}\left(\mathbf{Y}_{1}^{P}-\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j} \mathbf{Y}_{j}^{P}\right) \\
& +\left(\boldsymbol{\theta}_{t}-\lambda_{t}\left(\lambda^{P^{\prime}} \lambda^{P}\right)^{-1} \lambda^{P^{\prime}} \boldsymbol{\theta}^{P}\right)\left(\mathbf{Z}_{1}-\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j} \mathbf{Z}_{j}\right) \\
& -\lambda_{t}\left(\lambda^{P \prime} \lambda^{P}\right)^{-1} \lambda^{P^{\prime}}\left(\boldsymbol{\varepsilon}_{1}^{P}-\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j} \varepsilon_{j}^{P}\right) \\
& +\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j}\left(\varepsilon_{1 t}-\varepsilon_{j t}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
Suppose that there exist $\left\{w_{2}^{*}, \ldots, w_{J+1}^{*}\right\}$ such that Equation (2) (Exact Balance) holds. Then
$$
Y_{1 t}^{N}-\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j}^{*} Y_{j t}^{N}=R_{1 t}+R_{2 t}+R_{3 t}
$$
where
$$
\begin{aligned}
& R_{1 t}=\lambda_{t}\left(\lambda^{P^{\prime}} \lambda^{P}\right)^{-1} \lambda^{P \prime} \sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j}^{*} \varepsilon_{j}^{P} \\
& R_{2 t}=-\lambda_{t}\left(\lambda^{P \prime} \lambda^{P}\right)^{-1} \lambda^{P^{\prime}} \varepsilon_{1}^{P}
\end{aligned}
$$
and $R_{3 t}=\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j}^{*}\left(\varepsilon_{j t}-\varepsilon_{1 t}\right)$. Consider the case of $t>T_{0}$. Then, $R_{2 t}$ and $R_{3 t}$ have mean zero. Notice that,
$$
R_{1 t}=\sum_{j=2}^{J+1} w_{j}^{*} \sum_{s=1}^{T_{0}} \lambda_{t}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{T_{0}} \lambda_{n}^{\prime} \lambda_{n}\right)^{-1} \lambda_{s}^{\prime} \varepsilon_{j s}
$$

